# Child Parent Property Change in C#

Tags: c#, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a property in a class (e.g. `ParentClass`) in C# that is  binding with `ObservableCollection` of another class Type (e.g. `ChildClass`).  My question is how to change the value of `ChildClass` property by using the `ParentClass` property such that `RaisePropertyChanged("ParentProperty")` should get triggered?

I use this coding:

```
foreach (var pIn in ParentProperty.Where(ms => ms.Name == onNameUpdateObj.Name && ms.UnRead == true))
{
    if (pIn != null)
    {
         pIn.UnRead = false;
    }
}
```

`ParentProperty` is the property binding with `ObservableCollection<ChildClass>` and `ChildClass` contains the property `UnRead`.  When I change the value of `UnRead` `RaisePropertyChanged("ParentProperty")` returns `null`.  I want `RaisePropertyChanged("ParentProperty")` to be triggered whenever I change the property value of `pIn.UnRead`.

Comment: if ChildClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged specifically the UnRead  property then you shouldnt have a problem, post the UnRead code + the class defenition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` does not provide notifications for when one or more `properties` of the collection it maintains change, it only provides notifications for `when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed`.

If you want to know when a `property` in your collection changes, you need to implement a notification for that yourself.  Such a mechanism can be implemented with the aid of [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and/or [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx).

Comment: @SunnySingh - I've not done a `Refresh()` on and `ObservableCollection<t>` before myself, however, a quick and dirty `Google` suggests: `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(parentClass.ChildClasses).Refresh();` **might** work.  I would perhaps advise against this and rethink what it is you are attempting to achieve.